# Laravel resource controller testing gives NotFoundHttpException the second time

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I am encountering a very strange thing while doing testing with Laravel 4. It looks like a bug but there's probably a logical explanation.

I have replicated the "bug" in a clean Laravel install and here's my code:

My resource controller `/app/controllers/TestController.php`:

(Created with `php artisan controller:make TestController`)

```
class TestController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return Response::json(array());
    }

    // The end of the file is unchanged
```

In my `app/routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

// Note the composed part of the URL.
// My problem isn't present if I just use `myapi` or `path` as a url
Route::resource('myapi/path', 'TestController');
```

Added in `/app/test/ExampleTest.php`:

```
public function testTest()
{
    $res = $this->call('GET', 'myapi/path');

    // Until here everything works right
    $this->assertEquals(json_decode($res->getContent()), array());

    // Now I call the same URL a second time
    $res = $this->call('GET', 'myapi/path');

    $this->assertEquals(json_decode($res->getContent()), array());
}
```

Now I run phpunit and here's what I get:

```
There was 1 error:

1) ExampleTest::testTest
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: 

/home/me/Web/laraveltest/bootstrap/compiled.php:5531
/home/me/Web/laraveltest/bootstrap/compiled.php:4848
/home/me/Web/laraveltest/bootstrap/compiled.php:4836
/home/me/Web/laraveltest/bootstrap/compiled.php:4828
/home/me/Web/laraveltest/bootstrap/compiled.php:721
/home/me/Web/laraveltest/bootstrap/compiled.php:702
/home/me/Web/laraveltest/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
/home/me/Web/laraveltest/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:332
/home/me/Web/laraveltest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/ApplicationTrait.php:51
/home/me/Web/laraveltest/app/tests/ExampleTest.php:25
```

In my other project I get a slightly different backtrace, but I have the impression that's the same problem: (but I have no idea of why the other is compiled and this one not)

```
2) UnitModelTest::testOther
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: 

/home/me/Web/my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:148
/home/me/Web/my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1049
/home/me/Web/my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1017
/home/me/Web/my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:996
/home/me/Web/my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:775
/home/me/Web/my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:745
/home/me/Web/my-project/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
/home/me/Web/my-project/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:327
/home/me/Web/my-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/ApplicationTrait.php:51
/home/me/Web/my-project/app/tests/UnitModelTest.php:32
```

In both case the line given in the trace for the test file corresponds to the **second** `call` of the test.

As I noted in the comments of the `routes.php` file, if I use a simple url with no slash, the test passes without problem.

I have no problem when I use the api from the browser.

I found many topics related to the NotFoundHttpException on StackOverflow, but none looks like mine. This one is specifically present when testing and only trigger an error at the second call.

So what am I doing wrong here ? Or is it really a bug ?

Comment: What if you have to different test functions and call it only once in each of them?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Yes theres no problem if I do like you say. But I have a test where I query the controller, then do something, then requery it to see if values changed correctly (like are there 2 new items in the listing ?)

Comment: I don't really know the reason for your problem but as workaround you might be able to use two tests that [depend](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies) on each other

Comment: It would be a bit strange as the first test would contain no assertion. I could also put the first part in the `setUp()` function and then store variables as class members. I'll wait to see if something better comes. Otherwise I'll do it that way.

Comment: Our you could at least assert if the call works properly (200 response or something else you return)

Comment: One more thing. Since an URL without slash works. Have you tried putting the resource route inside a `Route::group` with prefix `myapi`?

Comment: I tested the group prefix. It gives exactly the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `call`s made with the same client will use the provided URI relatively. That means what you actually call is:

1. myapi/path
2. myapi/myapi/path

You can fix this if you add a preface the urls with a `/` to make them absolute to the root of the application.

```
public function testTest()
{
    $res = $this->call('GET', '/myapi/path');

    // Until here everything works right
    $this->assertEquals(json_decode($res->getContent()), array());

    // Now I call the same URL a second time
    $res = $this->call('GET', '/myapi/path');

    $this->assertEquals(json_decode($res->getContent()), array());
}
```

If you experience other issues like that it often helps to call

```
$this->refreshApplication();
```

*(This would also create a new `client` and therefore solve this issue as well)*

Comment: That did the trick! I had never read something that mention it. Even the documentation doesn't use a slash at the start of the urls.

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't. And it's not very obvious since everywhere in the framework you don't need them (e.g. in the route declaration)

Comment: Thank you! I ran into this problem and couldn't figure what was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

In my case this error happened because i change `public` directory name to `public_html` my solution was put this in the `\App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` `register` method.

```
public function register()
{
    // ...

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('public_html');
    });
}
```